# What am I doing wrong in this while loop

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to add this code to end of my Python program to ask if the user wants to start the program again or end it. If I say yes the program loops again but doesn't ask if the user wants to restart after it gets to the end. What am I missing?

```
    while Cont != "n" and Cont != "y":
        Cont=input("Do you want to draw another shape? (y/n): ")

        #Summary
        if Cont == "n":
            print("\n")
            print("Here is a summary of the shapes drawn:\n1)Horizontal Line",Horizontal_Line,"\n2)Vertical Line",Vertical_Line,"\n3)Rectangle",Rectangle,"\n4)Right Triangle",Right_Triangle,"\n5)Isosceles Triangle",Isosceles_Triangle,"\n6)???",Trapezoid,) 
            break
```

Comment: Your code suggest that the program should only repeat if `Cont` is neither `y` or `n`, because `while Cont != "n" and Cont != "y"` will only evaluate to true if `Cont` is anything other than `n` or `y`. Also, on an unrelated note: variable names is usually written in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop evaluation is wrong. The `Cont` variable will never storage `y` and `n` at the same time, that's why your programs never reach the loop.

You could ask first and then evaluate base on the decision.

```
while True:
    cont=input("Do you want to draw another shape? (y/n): ")       

    if Cont == "n":
        print("\n")
        print("Here is a summary of the shapes drawn:\n1)Horizontal Line",Horizontal_Line,"\n2)Vertical Line",Vertical_Line,"\n3)Rectangle",Rectangle,"\n4)Right Triangle",Right_Triangle,"\n5)Isosceles Triangle",Isosceles_Triangle,"\n6)???",Trapezoid,) 
        break
```